# Shopping cart promotion. Total quantity of different SKU condition

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, discount

I want to create a shopping cart promotion but can not get it to work.
What I need is that for a subset of products, when the total quantity in the cart is higher than 50, it should give a discount. I tried multiple promotions but somehow it always looks at the item quantity and not the total of all products.

Example of what is not working

[image: Prmotion rule]

[image: No discount when the total is 50]

[image: Yes discount when one item has qty 50]

Comment: Are they simple products? Or parts of configurable items?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it so that the SKUs are all listed on a single line. You'll need to change "SKU is" to "SKU is one of" and separate each SKU with a comma and a space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make a change to use `Is one of` when matching on SKU so that you make a set of SKUs that can match rather than multiple sku matches.

[image: multiple sku matching]